# Why MySQL isn't using my FULLTEXT indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM glean2_saves
WHERE username = '1d85d5aed8b02b3d6b0c155a563293ef'
AND ses_id = 'e4fa3ae216f5033fbd16d6c66370954c'
AND save_status =1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And the result is this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  glean2_saves    ref     save_status,username,ses_id     save_status     2   const   286315  Using where; Using filesort
```

Here are my indexes:

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  331837  A       
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   save_status BTREE   No  No  save_status 3   A   YES 
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   nickname    FULLTEXT    No  No  nickname    7374        YES 
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   username    FULLTEXT    No  No  username    7717        YES 
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   ses_id  FULLTEXT    No  No  ses_id  11442       YES
```

I do have indexes on the right columns, **but why are they not used**?
How come they are in the "possible keys" (save_status, username, ses_id) but only one "key" is actually used: save_status

Without the indexes, the query takes way too long (sometimes over 15 seconds), it should take less than one second. The database is over 330k entries.

Comment: As a note, the title of this is incorrect.  "Full Text" indexes refer to indexes used for text retrieval.  This question is just about a regular index on a character column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query, you want *one* index that covers the `where` and `order by` clauses.  That index would be:

```
glean2_saves(username, ses_id, save_status, id)
```

Note that because you are doing equality comparisons, the first three columns can be in any order.  But the last column needs to be `id` for the `order by`.

As for *why* MySQL is not using the individual indexes.  Let's just say that merging indexes for `where` clauses is a lot of work, and might result in more work than scanning one index and doing the tests for the remaining columns.